# Push into Firebase with unique ID

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I'm building my first iOS app and I'm using Firebase as my backend.

I'm trying to store an array into my Firebase backend like so:

```
Firebase* f = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://test.firebaseio.com/items"];
[f setValue:@{@"UNIQUE OBJECT ID HERE": @{@"meh": @"lol", @"hum": @"kek"}}];
```

It works as expected, but I need to have an unique id for each "object". Right now, every time that method runs Firebase just replaces the old data with the new one.

Coming from a web dev background, I know that in JavaScript I would do this:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://test.firebaseio.com/items");
ref.push({meh: "lol", hum: "kek")};
```

Which yields the expected result, since it gives the object above a name of "-IuxeSuSiNy6xiahCXa0".

How do I accomplish this in ObjC?

Comment: So what is a question about? How to generate an unique random string in Objective C?

Comment: That's one way to do it, yes. What I was wondering was how to avoid that all together and make Firebase generate that all by itself like it does on Javascript. I've looked into their API docs and can't find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase has build in system in Objective-C as well, but the syntax is a touch different.

```
Firebase * ref;

Firebase * autoId = [ref childByAutoId];
```

This:

```
Firebase* f = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://test.firebaseio.com/items"];
[f setValue:@{@"UNIQUE OBJECT ID HERE": @{@"meh": @"lol", @"hum": @"kek"}}];
```

Should be:

```
Firebase* f = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://test.firebaseio.com/items"];
[[f childByAutoId] setValue:@{@"meh": @"lol", @"hum": @"kek"}}];
```